# Netty - how to receive and response image over http?

Tags: java, image, http, netty

May I know how **Netty** works with Image over http?
Any sample or tutorial?

Basically I want to know:

1) how to receive client's uploaded image

2) how to reply image by http response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [example](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/3/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/example/http/upload) for receiving uploaded files.

Here is the [example](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/3/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/example/http/file) for serving any type of files, including image files.

Hope this helps.

Comment: See https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/file

Answer (score 0):

Image data is just like any other data; a stream of bytes (or octets, to be precise) that is meaningful in terms of the Content-Type, e.g. image/jpeg. Note also that the Content-Encoding might be of interest to handle compression/uncompression. There should be enough informaion in the example sources on netty.io to get you going.